# Convert QmouseEvent to QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent for a drag movement

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to move QGraphicsScene instead of moving my whole widget (which caused some graphical glitches due to the widget moving off-limit).

This is what I tried to do :

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    #super(SvgView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    self.svgItem.mousePressEvent(event)

    self.x += event.pos().x()
    self.y += event.pos().y()
    event.accept()
```

(notice that I'm not updating my self.x and self.y the right way, as this is a "drag" movement and I'm supposed to put the "delta" instead, but I don't know how to get it)

This doesn't work because svgItem expects a `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`.

I tried doing this mouseEvent on the scene instead of doing it on the QGraphicsView, but it doesn't make the item drag.

Is there anyway to do this without doing this conversion, and if it's necessary how can I do it?

Comment: "I want to move QGraphicsScene instead of moving my whole widget" This makes no sense, moving the `QGraphicsScene` does not move the `QGraphicsView`, and vice versa.  Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: My view has a background that I don't want to move. I only want to move the items that are on my view (an svg + it's background and border). I'm a complete beginner to Qt, so I may have misunderstood a thing or too about scenes :-) !

Comment: So even when are panning around the scene, you do not want the background to move relative to the view?  Also what do you mean by "items that are on my view"?  The view does not hold anything, only the scene.

Comment: if you want to move the `QGraphicsItems` in the `QGraphicsScene` you can just use the default drag'n'drop feature. you just have to make the items selectable and moveable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me SVG + Javascript is very understandable and with it I can do whatever I want. But I am struggling with PyQt for desktop app. Avaris helps me to understand something about event propagation in Qt. 
I wrote few lines for experimenting, but maybe it may help you. Not the best, but "eppur si muove":

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView): # as separate class
    def BlahBlah():
        print dir()

class Scene_w_ellipse(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scene_w_ellipse, self).__init__()
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,300,200)
        self.C = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(-4,-20,80,40)
        self.C.setPos(100,70)
        self.C.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        #self.C.mousePressEvent(QtGui.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent)
        self.addItem(self.C)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print dir()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.C.mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.C.mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

For your background, don't subclass, build it as separate class.